# Cannot resolve method 'setQuery(com.google.firebase.firestore.Query, androidx.paging.PagedList.Config, java.lang.Class VideoRVModel

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KFlE.png)

Cannot resolve method 'setQuery(com.google.firebase.firestore.Query, androidx.paging.PagedList.Config, java.lang.Class<com.example.videostreamapp.data.VideoRVModel>)'

Comment: That's most likely happening because your pass as the second argument an object of type [PagedList.Config](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/PagedList.Config) and not an [PagingConfig](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/paging/PagingConfig) object,  right?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)